# Обновление через API

Tags: php, laravel, api

Здравствуйте дорогие формучане!

Подскажите пожалуйста правильный ответ. Все действия будут происходить в **Framework Laravel**.
Есть php код с API доступом на другой сайт его пример:

```
public function check_update(){
    $data_array =  array(
        "product_id"  => $this->product_id,
        "current_version" => $this->current_version
    );
    $get_data = $this->call_api(
        'POST',
        $this->api_url.'api/check_update', 
        json_encode($data_array)
    );
    $response = json_decode($get_data, true);
    return $response;
}

public function download_update($update_id, $type, $version, $license = true, $client = true, $db_for_import = true){ 
    if(!empty($license)&&!empty($client)){
        $data_array =  array(
            "license_file" => null,
            "license_code" => $license,
            "client_name" => $client
        );
    }else{
        if(is_file($this->license_file)){
            $data_array =  array(
                "license_file" => file_get_contents($this->license_file),
                "license_code" => null,
                "client_name" => null
            );
        }else{
            $data_array =  array();
        }
    }
    ob_end_flush(); 
    ob_implicit_flush(true);  
    $version = str_replace(".", "_", $version);
    ob_start();
    $source_size = $this->api_url."api/get_update_size/main/".$update_id; 
    echo LB_TEXT_PREPARING_MAIN_DOWNLOAD."<br>";
    if(LB_SHOW_UPDATE_PROGRESS){echo '<script>document.getElementById(\'prog\').value = 1;</script>';}
    ob_flush();
    echo LB_TEXT_MAIN_UPDATE_SIZE." ".$this->get_remote_filesize($source_size)." ".LB_TEXT_DONT_REFRESH."<br>";
    if(LB_SHOW_UPDATE_PROGRESS){echo '<script>document.getElementById(\'prog\').value = 5;</script>';}
    ob_flush();
    $temp_progress = '';
    $ch = curl_init();
    $source = $this->api_url."api/download_update/main/".$update_id; 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $source);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_array);
    $this_server_name = getenv('SERVER_NAME')?:
        $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']?:
        getenv('HTTP_HOST')?:
        $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $this_http_or_https = ((
        (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])&&($_SERVER['HTTPS']=="on"))or
        (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'])and
            $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] === 'https')
    )?'https://':'http://');
    $this_url = $this_http_or_https.$this_server_name.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $this_ip = getenv('SERVER_ADDR')?:
        $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']?:
        $this->get_ip_from_third_party()?:
        gethostbyname(gethostname());
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'LB-API-KEY: '.$this->api_key, 
        'LB-URL: '.$this_url, 
        'LB-IP: '.$this_ip, 
        'LB-LANG: '.$this->api_language)
    );
    if(LB_SHOW_UPDATE_PROGRESS){curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, array($this, 'progress'));}
    if(LB_SHOW_UPDATE_PROGRESS){curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);}
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30); 
    echo LB_TEXT_DOWNLOADING_MAIN."<br>";
    if(LB_SHOW_UPDATE_PROGRESS){echo '<script>document.getElementById(\'prog\').value = 10;</script>';}
    ob_flush();
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if($http_status != 200){
        if($http_status == 401){
            curl_close($ch);
            exit("<br>".LB_TEXT_UPDATE_PERIOD_EXPIRED);
        }else{
            curl_close($ch);
            exit("<br>".LB_TEXT_INVALID_RESPONSE);
        }
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    $destination = $this->root_path."/update_".$version.".zip"; 
    $file = fopen($destination, "w+");
    if(!$file){
        exit("<br>".LB_TEXT_UPDATE_PATH_ERROR);
    }
    fputs($file, $data);
    fclose($file);
    if(LB_SHOW_UPDATE_PROGRESS){echo '<script>document.getElementById(\'prog\').value = 65;</script>';}
    ob_flush();
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $res = $zip->open($destination);
    if($res === TRUE){
        $zip->extractTo($this->root_path."/"); 
        $zip->close();
        unlink($destination);
        echo LB_TEXT_MAIN_UPDATE_DONE."<br><br>";
        if(LB_SHOW_UPDATE_PROGRESS){echo '<script>document.getElementById(\'prog\').value = 75;</script>';}
        ob_flush();
    }else{
        echo LB_TEXT_UPDATE_EXTRACTION_ERROR."<br><br>";
        ob_flush();
    }
    if($type == true){
        $source_size = $this->api_url."api/get_update_size/sql/".$update_id; 
        echo LB_TEXT_PREPARING_SQL_DOWNLOAD."<br>";
        ob_flush();
        echo LB_TEXT_SQL_UPDATE_SIZE." ".$this->get_remote_filesize($source_size)." ".LB_TEXT_DONT_REFRESH."<br>";
        if(LB_SHOW_UPDATE_PROGRESS){echo '<script>document.getElementById(\'prog\').value = 85;</script>';}
        ob_flush();
        $temp_progress = '';
        $ch = curl_init();
        $source = $this->api_url."api/download_update/sql/".$update_id;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $source);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_array);
        $this_server_name = getenv('SERVER_NAME')?:
            $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']?:
            getenv('HTTP_HOST')?:
            $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $this_http_or_https = ((
            (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])&&($_SERVER['HTTPS']=="on"))or
            (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'])and
                $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] === 'https')
        )?'https://':'http://');
        $this_url = $this_http_or_https.$this_server_name.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $this_ip = getenv('SERVER_ADDR')?:
            $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']?:
            $this->get_ip_from_third_party()?:
            gethostbyname(gethostname());
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'LB-API-KEY: '.$this->api_key, 
            'LB-URL: '.$this_url, 
            'LB-IP: '.$this_ip, 
            'LB-LANG: '.$this->api_language)
        ); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
        echo LB_TEXT_DOWNLOADING_SQL."<br>";
        if(LB_SHOW_UPDATE_PROGRESS){echo '<script>document.getElementById(\'prog\').value = 90;</script>';}
        ob_flush();
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        $http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if($http_status!=200){
            curl_close($ch);
            exit(LB_TEXT_INVALID_RESPONSE);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        $destination = $this->root_path."/update_sql_".$version.".sql"; 
        $file = fopen($destination, "w+");
        if(!$file){
            exit(LB_TEXT_UPDATE_PATH_ERROR);
        }
        fputs($file, $data);
        fclose($file);
        echo LB_TEXT_SQL_UPDATE_DONE."<br><br>";
        if(LB_SHOW_UPDATE_PROGRESS){echo '<script>document.getElementById(\'prog\').value = 95;</script>';}
        ob_flush();
        if(is_array($db_for_import)){
            if(!empty($db_for_import["db_host"])&&!empty($db_for_import["db_user"])&&!empty($db_for_import["db_name"])){
                $db_host = strip_tags(trim($db_for_import["db_host"]));
                $db_user = strip_tags(trim($db_for_import["db_user"]));
                $db_pass = strip_tags(trim($db_for_import["db_pass"]));
                $db_name = strip_tags(trim($db_for_import["db_name"]));
                $con = @mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
                if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
                    echo LB_TEXT_UPDATE_WITH_SQL_IMPORT_FAILED;
                }else{
                    $templine = '';
                    $lines = file($destination);
                    foreach($lines as $line){
                        if(substr($line, 0, 2) == '--' || $line == '')
                            continue;
                        $templine .= $line;
                        $query = false;
                        if(substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';'){
                            $query = mysqli_query($con, $templine);
                            $templine = '';
                        }
                    }
                    @chmod($destination,0777);
                    if(is_writeable($destination)){
                        unlink($destination);
                    }
                    echo LB_TEXT_UPDATE_WITH_SQL_IMPORT_DONE;
                }
            }else{
                echo LB_TEXT_UPDATE_WITH_SQL_IMPORT_FAILED;
            }
        }else{
            echo LB_TEXT_UPDATE_WITH_SQL_DONE;
        }
        if(LB_SHOW_UPDATE_PROGRESS){echo '<script>document.getElementById(\'prog\').value = 100;</script>';}
        ob_flush();
    }else{
        if(LB_SHOW_UPDATE_PROGRESS){echo '<script>document.getElementById(\'prog\').value = 100;</script>';}
        echo LB_TEXT_UPDATE_WITHOUT_SQL_DONE;
        ob_flush();
    }
    ob_end_flush(); 
}
```

Когда нажимаю скачать в админ панели обновления получаю следующую ошибку:

> Подготовка к загрузке основного обновления...
> Основной размер обновления: -1 B (Пожалуйста, не обновляйте страницу).
> Загрузка основного обновления...
> Сервер вернул неверный ответ, обратитесь в службу поддержки.

Смотрим на: **Основной размер обновления: -1 B** (скорее всего из-за этого получает сервер ошибку) видим что размер -1B, при этом сам архив весит 12М.

Подскажите решение!

Comment: Честно говоря, смотреть больно. Вы предлагаете в этом бардаке разбираться? А, ещё, прочтите [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/)

Comment: Так же у Laravel есть [HTTP Client](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client), можно будет сократить и сделать более читабельным Ваш код.

Comment: @InDevX Я прошу помочь, а не разбираться.

Comment: @Simon
Этот код сгенерирован, а не написан. (В теорий он все же написан). Я его подключил отдельным контроллером.

Comment: "Я прошу помочь, а не разбираться." -- А как Вам помочь, если не разбираться в коде?

Comment: @Simon Решимость пробовать – первейшее свойство писателя. Я пока так код понимаю. Я просто самоучка и нет наставника, кто-бы палкой бил за кревоту.